# Is there a way to copy EBS snapshot to another account in other region? (cross-region,cross-account)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-ebs

I'm trying to find out if it's possible to copy a `snapshot` from one `account` to another in different `region` in **one go**, without intermediate ( meaning copy/share to the other account then copy from the new account to the other region ), using `lambda function` and `boto3`.
I have searched in `aws` documentation but with no luck

Comment: Try modifying the permission. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ebs-modifying-snapshot-permissions.html

Comment: here is what the doc says about sharing : 
`Snapshots are constrained to the Region in which they were created. To share a snapshot with another Region, copy the snapshot to that Region. `

Comment: I need to copy the snapshot to another account which is in other region, doing the cross-region-account

Comment: Cross-region sharing will not work without copying it to target region even within same account, so I don't think so

Comment: AWS Accounts are not limited to a single region. So, it is not accurate to say "another account which is in other region". Instead, you will need to separate the process into two steps: Copying between accounts and Copying between regions. These can be done in either order, but need to be done separately, not together.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein pardon my inaccurate phrase, but I'm just starting with aws. The thing is we don't want to do extra copies by doing the cross-account sharing and the cross-region copying, we were wondering if there might be a way around to do both at once

Comment: No, they need to be done as separate operations. Snapshots can only be shared within the same region.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you need such "complex" logic, it can be implemented with either `CloudFormation` or `Terraform`. The flow will be like the comments suggested, copy to another region and give permission to another account.

[This](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/%C2%AD%C2%AD%C2%ADautomating-cross-region-cross-account-snapshot-copies-with-the-snapshot-tool-for-amazon-aurora/) AWS blog speaks of a similar requirement with example `CloudFormation` templates [here](https://github.com/awslabs/aurora-snapshot-tool/tree/master/cftemplates).

If you are unfamiliar with `CloudFormation`, you can get started with their [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/Welcome.html) but it isn't something you can do when in a hurry. Just good practice you can develop early on.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, so unfortunately  doing cross-account and cross-region at one go, isn't possible :/